# MySQL view extremely slow despite indexes

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query, view, query-performance

I'm having an issue with a view, when I make a query it brings CPU to 100% and it keeps loading.

The view is:

https://pastebin.com/ZgB7rr91

channel_data_60 table contains about 1,200,000 records:

https://pastebin.com/mkmQH39p

and this is the source table:

https://pastebin.com/2xiCiwSM

and a screenshot of the EXPLAIN:

[image: EXPLAIN SELECT]

I read around and it seems UNION makes this kind of issues but I made a test without it and the query keeps loading forever.

**Any help? Is the EXPLAIN result showing something useful?**

Comment: I was able to add a dirty workaround by replacing the channel_data_60 table with a mirror view limited to the latest 10,000 records. Net the most elegant thing, though.

Comment: Please do not use [screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). Also, please add any additional information you have to the question itself - makes for easier reading!

Comment: @Vérace I'd like to make it clearer but what do you suggest for showing a table with 11 columns instead of a screenshot?